# QT - Detecting which button was pressed

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with the usage of `Application::sender`. I have a few `QPushButtons` and in one function, I want to detect which button was pressed.

I got to know that using `Application::sender` might be the solution, however I have troubles with it. Namely I get two errors:

- call to non-static member function without an object argument
- 'sender' is a protected member of 'QObject'

And here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_button_click()
{
    unsigned long i=0;
    for(; i<buttons.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(buttons[i] == QApplication::sender())
            break;
    }
    if(checks[i]->checkState() == false)
        buttons[i]->setText("Undone");
    else
        buttons[i]->setText("Done!");
}
```

Where variable `buttons` is a `vector` of `QPushButton *`

Comment: In *my* experience; if you ever have to use `sender()` there's a flaw in your design. Sure, it can be a useful hack, but there are usually better ways.

Comment: I am new to QT. I have been doing it only for 3 days so I am trying my best :D

Comment: Jesper Juhl: I don't see a reason not to use `sender()`. It is used by the offiical examples http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calculator-example.html - QSignalMapper would be a way, but is deprecated. Can you elaborate why the use of `sender()` is a design flaw?.

Comment: @user3606329 it completely breaks isolation between classes and couples them tightly. Also, if you read the official documentation you'll see the Qt people themselves warning about it with words like [Warning: This function violates the object-oriented principle of modularity.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method sender() of the object where your slot is, not the static member of QApplication.

In other words, remove QApplication:: and your code should work as expected.

Comment: Now it's running, but I don't get expected result and thing like this is displayed:
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_button_click()

Comment: The warning is because the slots named "on_something1_something2" are connected automatically to the object named something1 and the signal named something2. In this case there is no object named button with a signal named click. That warning is not relevant. What do you mean by don't get the expected results?

Comment: Like you probably saw in my code, the thing I want to achieve is to get word "Done!" or "Undone" written on the button (depending if CheckBox with same "I" is ticked or not)

Comment: First of all, you should have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to post an **MCVE**. Second, checkState() doesn't return a boolean, so that if condition is simply wrong. Maybe you mean [isChecked()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) ?

Comment: Yes it should be isChecked(), my bad. However after changing it into isChecked() it still doesn't change this button text.

Comment: Should I somehow call this function on event? Coz the only things that I did are: creating a declaration of function in header and "describing" it in .cpp file. I think that I should somehow connect it, shouldn't I?

Comment: Of course you must connect them! Start by studying the official documentation and how signal and slots work. Also, please conform to this website policies: don't keep asking things in comments, update your answer when needed, etc. stack overflow is not a shortcut to avoid studying.

Answer (score 0):

sender() returns QObject. You need QPushButton so your have to use casting. This code will work:

```
QPushButton *button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
button->setText("New Text");
```